# How to delete a remote event receiver with powershell? I get an access denied

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

First than all, I am global admin and also site collection administrator in the site collection where I am trying the below code.

Error its in spanish, but it says Access denied

```
Failed to delete receiver - error:  Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Acceso denegado. No tiene el permiso 
necesario para realizar esta acción o tener acceso a este recurso."
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException
```

The code is:

```
$loadInfo1 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
$loadInfo2 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")
$webUrl = Read-Host -Prompt "HTTPS URL for your SP Online 2013 site" #"https://michaelbl.sharepoint.com" 
$username = Read-Host -Prompt "Email address for logging into that site" #michaelbl@michaelbl.onmicrosoft.com" 
$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Password for $username" -AsSecureString


    $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/dev.site.intranet") 
    $ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $password)


    $list = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Clientes")
    $ctx.Load($list)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    $eventReceivers = $list.EventReceivers
    $ctx.Load($eventReceivers)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    $specifiedEr = $null
    try
    {
        foreach ($er in $eventReceivers)
        {
            if ($er.ReceiverName -eq "CLIENTES_ITEMADDED")
            {
                $specifiedEr = $er
            }
        }

        if ($specifiedEr -ne $null -and !$specifiedEr.ServerObjectIsNull.Value)
        {
            $specifiedEr.DeleteObject()
            $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
            Write-Host "Receiver deleted successfully"
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Error "Failed to find receiver with name '$receiverName'"
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Error "Failed to delete receiver - error:  $_"
    }
```

Comment: weird enough, if I do it via CSOM in the app itself, I have the same error, how am I supposed to delete the RER?